# Generalizing `macro_rules!` matches

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I have a macro that calls another macro in a slightly different way based on the arguments provided.

```rust
macro_rules! do_things {
    ($($e:expr),*) => { ... }
}


macro_rules! do_more_things {
    ($($e:expr),* ; $val1:expr, $cond:expr) => {
        {
            do_things!($($e),*);
            if $cond {
                do_things!(MAGIC_CONST_1 | $val1);
                call_something($cond);
            } else {
                do_things!(MAGIC_CONST_2 | $val1, $cond);
            }
        }
    };
    ($($e:expr),* ; $val1:expr, $val2:expr, $cond:expr) => {
        {
            do_things!($($e),*);
            if $cond {
                do_things!(MAGIC_CONST_1 | $val1, $val2);
                call_something($cond);
            } else {
                do_things!(MAGIC_CONST_2 | $val1, $val2, $cond);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

How can I generalize it to eliminate two very similar branches?

If it helps, `do_things!(a, b);` in this case is equivalent to `do_things!(a); do_things!(b)`.

Comment: I don't think you can simplify that.

Comment: If you use a different separator between the `val`s and the cond, e.g., another semicolon, then you should be able to merge the two cases with something like `$val1:expr,? $val2:expr ;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with exactly that invocation, but you can either rearrange the arguments so that the condition comes before all the values:

```rust
macro_rules! do_more_things {
    ($($e:expr),* ; $cond:expr, $val1:expr $(, $val2:expr)? ) => {
        {
            do_things!($($e),*);
            if $cond {
                do_things!(MAGIC_CONST_1 | $val1 $(, $val2)?);
                call_something($cond);
            } else {
                do_things!(MAGIC_CONST_2 | $val1 $(, $val2)?, $cond);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

alternatively you can change the separator between the condition and the values to something distinct like @BallpointBen suggests